# Netbeans open maven project with pom.yml

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I'm trying to load a maven project in netbeans which contains pom.yml instead of pom.xml.

When I go to the directory where the application is present, Netbeans is not recognising it as a project/app. It is showing up as a regular directory. When I click on the directory, it is taking me right inside instead of opening it.

I checked in the plugins repo to see if there are any related plugins, but unfortunately, there aren't any.

Can anyone help me out please?

Thanks

Comment: Please could you explain why you need to have `pom.yml` instead of  `pom.xml` ?

Comment: It has been developed quite some time back... I was trying to explore the application. Looks like netbeans has no support for yml. But I was able to import it in Intellij..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pom.yml` is used by the [Polyglot for Maven](https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven) extension. Netbeans has no support for it.

A working solution is to convert the `pom.yml` back to `pom.xml`.

with Maven 3.3.1+ run following command

```
mvn io.takari.polyglot:polyglot-translate-plugin:0.1.15:translate \
  -Dinput=pom.xml \
  -Doutput=pom.yml
```

**note:** Newer versions of the `polyglot-translate-plugin` have a bug see [issue #96](https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven/issues/96). Which lead to the error

```
... A required class was missing while executing \
  io.takari.polyglot:polyglot-translate-plugin:0.1.16:translate: \
  org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamReader
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to import it in intellij